# ovr camera rotating in the preview

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, oculus

I'm building a game for oculus with unity. I've imported the ovr and added an OVRPlayerController as it is in the ovr sample scenes. In the preview I have only the abilty to look 360 degrees around the camera. How can I change it to an ovr camera that can also look to the floor or the sky, namely at any direction I choose, just as it is with the real ovr device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your are right. **OVRPlayerController** (object) can just rotate 360 degrees around horizontally.

There is a simple way to look 360 degrees horizontally and verically. This is simple to achieve the goal.

### And please remember

1. turn the component **OVR Player Controller** (script) down
2. make the position of this object(OVRCameraRig) attached this script is 0,0,0

### How to use:

1. Ctrl is fire
2. Press alt to rotate

### All is Like

[image]

### References

The script is from peterept, [script original link](http://talesfromtherift.com/unity-vr-editor-mouse-look-script/)

Comment: Would be nice if you credited the source of the script to TalesFromTheRift.com . See my answer below.

Comment: Sorry, I folked the script from yours, I hope what I did does not offense you. I really like your blog, and nearlly read all your posts.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I'm glad you like it. I'm sorry, I didn't mean what I wrote to sound quite like it did - I'm really glad my work is getting out and helping others. That's the point. :-)

Comment: I am really glad to meet you here. @peterept , your posts are really practical and thanks for your work

Comment: Thanks @tim. Good to meet you too!

Answer (score 3):

An alternate answer is that you need to purchase an Oculus DK2 (or shortly the CV1). With that plugged in when you press PLAY in Unity then you can turn the head set in any direction (and move position). The most important thing is you can live preview the scene through the headset.

Oh, and it would be nice if the author of the previous answer credited the script in the gist to me, as I wrote it and published on my VR blog []-)

[VR Mouse Look - TalesFromTheRift.com](http://talesfromtherift.com/unity-vr-editor-mouse-look-script/)